# How to translateX an element proportionally to its own width and not its parent or screen width with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to adapt [this pure CSS text scroll tutorial](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/scrolling-text-css) to my project. I found that it does not work when scrolled element width is longer than its container width. It stops scrolling too early while element is still visible.

I examined it a bit and managed to identify the problem but it is difficult for me to fix it as I do not really know much about CSS. Reason why it does not work is the final `translateX(-100%)` moves text by `100%` of the container size, not the scrolled element size. This causes the animation to reset while text is still visible.

Please take a look at the snippet I prepared here below

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.content {
  transformBox: content-box;
  MozTransform: translateX(-100%);
  WebkitTransform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                now this is just some crazy long text, much wider than its parent container
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expected result is: text should not be visible because it should be moved entirely to the left outside of the screen by `transformX(-100%)`.

I think if someone finds how to `transformX(-100%)` by the element width, that would fix the problem with the scroller. I was researching it a bit and I found [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) property that indicates the reference element to the CSS `transform` function. I did try all the possible values but it did not make any change and now I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `width` into content rule `width: fit-content;`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {  
  /* animation properties */  
  width:fit-content;
  -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
}

/* for Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes my-animation {
  from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

/* for Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                now this is just some crazy long text, much wider than its parent container
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
fit-content(<length-percentage>)
```

Uses the fit-content formula with the available space replaced by the specified argument, i.e. min(max-content, max(min-content, ))

Reference:

- [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: Thank you so much! It would never occur to me so I am super glad I asked!

Answer (score -1):

It is working my side

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.content {
width:fit-content;
  /* animation properties */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  
  -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
}

/* for Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes my-animation {
  from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

/* for Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                now this is just some crazy long text, much wider than its parent container
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work as OP said the content will not show all.

Comment: thanks for the answer, when I run your snippet it resets before the word "parent" fully appears, does the whole text move to the left when you run it?

Comment: @Marek: I did not understand. Please share expected result image if possible